# rotate mysql query in pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

How can I rotate select by a given number.

I want to rotate select items in each visit of a visitor.

Also I have four categories Premium,Gold,free,and Recommend

On first visit, the item is displayed.Pagination also used(On first page of pagination)

On second visit, the second Premium,Gold,Free,Recommend moves Upwards and the oldest goes to the last page, last item.(On same Page)

On third visit, the third come first and the second goes to last page, last item just after newest.(On Same Page)

I capture the visit count with a cookie on the first page.

But how can I select circularly? In categories Manner

```
Heres My Sql Query But This Is Not Worked For Pagination And Categorywised
{
 $pagination_limit=10;
 (SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY whatever LIMIT $n+1, $pagination_limit) UNION ALL
 (SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY whatever LIMIT $n)     
}
```

Comment: Why not add timestamp on item when it is shown, and the order by it ASC.

Comment: Can you show us actual example of the page contents? Is it e.g. on first visit `page1: item1, item2, item3 | page2: item4, item5` and on second visit `page1: item2, item3, item4 | page2: item5, item1`? What do have categories to do with that? Do all the items selected always have the same category?

Comment: e.g.premium1,premiunm2,premium3,gold1,gold2,gold3,free1,free2,free3
after page refresh should be premium2,premiunm3,preminum1,gold2,gold3,gold1,........so

Comment: @KaustubhBhujbal All premium{1..3}, gold{1..3}, free{1..3} on the same page? How does paging interact with that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have pagination I guess you have enough results as to need a second and third pages.

Now, if you paginate, your engine will apply the pagination to the top query and paste the bottom results to every page.

A functional, though not really elegant solution, would be to wrap the union and paginate over the result afterwards

```
SELECT foo FROM
(
    (SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY whatever OFFSET  $n+1) 
UNION ALL
    (SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY whatever LIMIT $n)
) as unionresult
LIMIT ($pagenumber * $pagination_limit), $pagination_limit
```

small prints: I leave to you the task of evaluating the variables properly. Of course you should evaluate ($pagenumber * $pagination_limit) before passing it to the query.